# Adding value to property in appsettings.json and convert it to json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

In ASP.NET Core web application in appsettings.json I have:

```
"SVAML" : {
        'instructions':[
         {
            'name' : 'PlayFiles',
            'ids' : ['inside controller put string value here']
         }
        ],

        'action': {
            'name' : 'Continue'
        }
}
```

Inside my controller I can access the value of it with _configuration["SVAML"], what I need is put the value inside controller and send it as json after putting this value, like JObject.Parse(_configuration["SVAML"]).toString() as body of request.

Comment: You can use `IOptions<T>` with necessary values and inject its instance to controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class for SVAML and serialize it.